# Perl sub reference syntax

Tags: perl

there - just started learning Perl.

This is what I'm doing to get an array into a subfunction - can it be done simpler in 1 line?

```
sub my_sub {
    my $ref_array = shift;
    my @array = @$ref_array;
}
```

Comment: Can *what* be done simpler?  What are you trying to do? Why copy the array in the first place??

Comment: Why are you using pass by reference on a single array, and then going to the trouble to make a completely new copy of it?  Why not just use `@_` *in situ*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the effect of the `shift` as well,

```
sub my_sub {
    my @array = @{+shift};
}
```

The [unary `+` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Symbolic-Unary-Operators) forces `shift` to be treated as an expression, not a variable name.  (Otherwise `@{shift}` means the same as `@shift`.)

Comment: This is pretty useless. I don’t believe the poster explained what he needs done well enough.  Also, I despise tricksy `+shift` for people who can't be bothered to write the infinitely clearer `shift()`.

Comment: TMTOWTDI; I like `+shift` better than `shift()`.  Honestly, this is closer to OP's original than other answers are, and I don't think there's enough context to say that this *isn't* the right thing to do.

Comment: IMHO "`+shift`" is a lot less readable and maintainable. And as tchrist noted in a separate comment, there's no seeming point to passing an array by reference only to turn it into a non-referenced array by copying.

Comment: Lately, I've been writing `@{shift @_}` in situations where I need to disambiguate from a bareword.  Does the job and uses the extra characters to actually explain what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to not worry about it being an arrayref -- just leave it that way and use it in the rest of your sub as-is.

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify just as

```
sub my_sub { 
  my @array = @{$_[0]};
}
```

Where `@_` is the default array/list, used in parameter passing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a heck of a lot cheaper:

```
local *array = shift();
```

Comment: And not the least bit equivalent.

Comment: In trying to learn the mid-level Perl magic, can I ask, what is it that you are setting to what here? Are you setting a reference to @array to the arrayref that has been passed in? How do you know that you create @array and not %array or $array? Where can I learn more about this * operator (perlop?). Thanks!

Comment: @tchrist: Why the hostility? It *would* make your posts better if you provided a little more explanation. If you think his example is "nonsense", it would be useful to explain *why* in your own answer and then explain why your alternative is better. There is an art to giving good answers, and getting upset in the comments is not a sign you're on that path.

Comment: @Cody - leaving aside communications issues (I am eminently less qualified to argue writing styles that tchrist, independently of which of you I agree with), he is correct on substance. The OP basically asked an ambiguous question that doesn't HAVE an answer as asked:

Comment: @Cody,@hobbs - 1. if he asked "how do I pass array to a method by reference" and access it, the answer is "use `$arr->[$i]` without bothering to stuff arrayref into array"; 2. If he asked "how do I pass an array by VALUE", the answer is "just pass the bleeding array in without a reference in the first place"; 3. If he asked "how to pass an array by reference and then make a copy of it", the answer is "unless there's a good reason to do it just this way, it's a bad idea to do so - either pass by value OR by reference; and if you DO have a reason, the code you have is the most readable possible"

Comment: @DVK: To be honest, I neither know nor care much about substance. I've never written a Perl script in my life. I was just observing the comments that had been made (and now deleted), as they were being flagged as spam by a number of users. I assumed this was not necessarily tchrist's true intention, so it would be polite to let him know that was the case and make a few suggestions on improvements. Now back to your regularly scheduled discussions. ;-)

Comment: @Joel - (1) I would strongly suggest you ask your question as a separate SO Perl question (you can link to this answer in it) - it's worth its own extended explanation. (2) "`*`" is called a "glob" (which gives you hellovatime googling for it since there's of course the similarly named `glob()` function for listing files :) . Among good references are http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html  , "Symbol Tables" entry in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Symbol-Tables and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Passing-Symbol-Table-Entries-%28typeglobs%29