# Demystifying the Perl glob (*)

Tags: perl, glob

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4833919/468327) the poster asked how to do the following in one line:

```
sub my_sub {
    my $ref_array = shift;
    my @array = @$ref_array;
}
```

which with my knowledge of the basic Perl magic I would avoid by simply using something like:

```
sub my_sub {
    my $ref_array = shift;
    for (@$ref_array) {
      #do somthing with $_ here
    };

    #use $ref_array->[$element] here
}
```

However in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833919/perl-sub-reference-syntax/4833976#4833976) one of SO's local monks tchrist suggested:

```
sub my_sub {
  local *array = shift();
  #use @array here
}
```

When I asked

> In trying to learn the mid-level Perl
>   magic, can I ask, what is it that you
>   are setting to what here? Are you
>   setting a reference to @array to the
>   arrayref that has been passed in? How
>   do you know that you create @array and
>   not %array or $array? Where can I
>   learn more about this * operator
>   (perlop?). Thanks!

I was suggested to ask it as a new post, though he did give nice references. Anyway, here goes? Can someone please explain what gets assigned to what and how come @array gets created rather than perhaps %array or $array? Thanks.

Comment: You can probably glean several important insights into typeglobs from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807231/how-can-i-test-if-i-can-write-to-a-filehandle/4200474#4200474), none of which have yet been touched upon here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assignment to a glob

```
*glob = VALUE
```

contains some magic that depends on the type of `VALUE` (i.e., return value of, say, `Scalar::Util::reftype(VALUE)`). If `VALUE` is a reference to a scalar, array, hash, or subroutine, then *only* that entry in the symbol table will be overwritten.

This idiom

```
local *array = shift();
#use @array here
```

works as documented when the first argument to the subroutine is an array reference. If the first argument was instead, say, a scalar reference, then only `$array` and not `@array` would be affected by the assignment.

A little demo script to see what is going on:

```
no strict;

sub F {
  local *array = shift;

  print "\@array = @array\n";
  print "\$array = $array\n";
  print "\%array = ",%array,"\n";
  print "------------------\n";
}

$array = "original scalar";
%array = ("original" => "hash");
@array = ("orignal","array");

$foo = "foo";
@foo = ("foo","bar");
%foo = ("FOO" => "foo");

F ["new","array"];        # array reference
F \"new scalar";          # scalar reference
F {"new" => "hash"};      # hash reference
F *foo;                   # typeglob
F 'foo';                  # not a reference, but name of assigned variable
F 'something else';       # not a reference
F ();                     # undef
```

---

Output:

```
@array = new array
$array = original scalar
%array = originalhash
------------------
@array = orignal array
$array = new scalar
%array = originalhash
------------------
@array = orignal array
$array = original scalar
%array = newhash
------------------
@array = foo bar
$array = foo
%array = FOOfoo
------------------
@array = foo bar
$array = foo
%array = FOOfoo
------------------
@array =
$array =
%array =
------------------
@array = orignal array
$array = original scalar
%array = originalhash
------------------
```

Additional doc at [`perlmod`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlmod#Symbol_Tables_______) and [`perldata`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perldata#Typeglobs_and_Filehandles___). Back in the days before references were a part of Perl, this idiom was helpful for passing arrays and hashes into subroutines.

Comment: Don't forget what happens when the RHS to a  typeglob assignment happens to be neither a typeglob nor a reference but string.  Also consider what happens when the operand of the `*` sigil is a string not a bareword. Finally, consider `local`.

Comment: As this answer shows, assignment to a glob fills different slots depending on the reference type.  You can tersely ensure that you have the proper type like so:  `local *array = \@{shift @_}`.  The reference/dereference pair `\@` is transparent if the ref is an array, but will throw an error otherwise.

Comment: I am still trying to read some of the things in the link that tchrist posted in the comment to the question, however, this answers my actual question very well. Thanks! and I think I am understanding at least some of the basics of the symbol table to boot!

Answer (score 3):

With my admittedly less-than-wizard knowledge of Perl, I'll venture an answer. The * operator assigns the symbol table entry. As I understand it, @array, %array, and $array all refer to the same symbol table entry for the string 'array', but to different fields in that entry: the ARRAY, HASH, and SCALAR fields. So assigning `local *array = shift;` actually assigns the entire local symbol table entry for 'array' (including the ARRAY, HASH, and SCALAR fields) to what was passed used in the caller.

Comment: If the thing assigned is a glob or a globref, yes; otherwise it's more complicated.  Actually, its more complicated anyway, because a symbol table entry is like a "glob variable" that holds a "glob value", and the assignment sets the value part, not the variable itself.