# Perl : Two packages in same file cannot import same package?

Tags: perl, perl-module

This is an interesting Perl behaviour. (atleast to me :) )

I have two packages `PACKAGE1` and `PACKAGE2` which exports function with same name `Method1()`.

As there will be so many packages which will export this same function, `use`-ing everything in a Perl file will be tedious. So, I have created a general include file `INCLUDES.pm` which will have these `use`s.

INCLUDES.pm:

```
use PACKAGE1;
use PACKAGE2;

1;
```

PACKAGE1.pm:

```
package PACKAGE1;

use Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw (
          Method1
);

sub Method1{
print "PACKAGE1_Method1 \n";
}

1;
```

PACKAGE2.pm:

```
package PACKAGE2;

use Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw (
    Method1
);

sub Method1{
    print "PACKAGE2_Method1 \n";
}

1;
```

Tests.pl:

```
##################first package################
package Test1;
use INCLUDES;
my @array = values(%INC);
print  "@array  \n";

Method1();

##################second package################
package Test2;
use INCLUDES;  #do "INCLUDES.pm";
my @array = values(%INC);
print  "@array  \n";

Method1();
```

The motive is, only the latest package's `Method1()` should be used in any Perl file.

The output surprises me.
I would expect that both `Method1()` calls in `Tests.pl` should be success.
But only the first `Method1()` executes, the second `Method1()` call says "undefined".

OUTPUT:

```
C:/Perl/site/lib/sitecustomize.pl PACKAGE1.pm C:/Perl/lib/Exporter.pm PACKAGE2
.pmINCLUDES.pm

PACKAGE2_Method1

C:/Perl/site/lib/sitecustomize.pl PACKAGE1.pm C:/Perl/lib/Exporter.pm PACKAGE2
.pm INCLUDES.pm

Undefined subroutine &Test2::Method1 called at C:\Temp\PackageSample\Tests.pl line 15.
```

Do somebody have any answers/views on this?

**The actual scenario:**

the methods in multiple Perl modules will be having same name. But the methods from the High preference perl module should only be used.

**For example, if `PACKAGE1` contains `Method1(), Method2()` & `PACKAGE2` contains only `Method1()`, then `Method1()` should be used from `PACKAGE2` & `Method2()` should be used from `PACKAGE1`**

Basically I want to achieve a Hierarchy among modules based on Preference. Is there any way for this?

Comment: While I can try to dream up some way to make it "work" I have two questions. 1) What should the second output be ("PACKAGE2_Method1" as well?). 2) Could you use some kind of class dispatch so that you don't have this giant ambiguity, it seems like it will be a debugging nightmare for someone down the road.

Comment: Yes. the second output will be also "PACKAGE2_Method1". The actual scenario is that, the methods in multiple Perl modules will be having same name. But the methods from the High preference perl module should only be used. For example, if `PACKAGE1` contains `Method1(), Method2()` & `PACKAGE2` contains only `Method1()`, then `Method1()` should be taken from `PACKAGE2` & `Method2()` should be taken from `PACKAGE1`. Basically I want to achieve a Hierarchy among modules based on Preference.

Comment: I agree with Joel that this sounds like a maintenance nightmare in the making - when the maintenance programmer (quite likely a future version of yourself) sees a call to `Method1`, he won't know where to look for its definition and will, very likely, look in the wrong place and attempt to debug code that isn't even being run. When you say "Hierarchy among modules", that gives me the impression that you're trying to reinvent object-oriented inheritance and polymorphism; if so, use the existing, proven OO techniques instead of reinventing them poorly.

Answer (score 4):

In Perl, [`use Module`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) is equivalent to

```
BEGIN { require Module; Module->import; }
```

But [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) caches the list of modules that have been required.  It only loads the module once per Perl process.  So only the first `use IMPORTS` does anything.  Since your `IMPORTS` module doesn't have an `import` method, nothing happens when you `use` it again.

I'm not quite sure what you're attempting to accomplish.  Perhaps your IMPORTS module should be an actual package, with an `import` method that exports whatever functions you want.  That way, each `use IMPORTS` would export functions into the package that called it.

Comment: I had spent some time working on how to do it "right" (actually I still think the design is fundamentally flawed, I mean "working"), but I was scratching my head on why one worked and the other didn't. You are certainly right about the caching prevents the second. What I still can't figure out is how the first worked?

Comment: @JoelBerger, the first one works because there's no `package` statement in `IMPORTS.pm`.  So the active package when `IMPORTS.pm` loads is still `Test1`, and the `use PACKAGE` statements import functions into that package.  But because it's already loaded, no code is executed by the second `use IMPORTS`.

Comment: Now I could understand why `do "INCLUDES.pm"` works for this condition. because, `do` does not check whether module is already loaded. Am I right?

Comment: Please check the edited question. I have given the scenario what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @InnovWelt, yes, `do` executes the code in `IMPORTS.pm` every time, but `use` executes it only once per process.

Comment: to be clear, if setup correctly, even on repeated calls, `use` will still call the package's `import` method.

Answer (score 3):

`use MyPackage` is equivalent to `BEGIN{ require MyPackage; MyPackage->import }`. Inheriting from Exporter sets up an `import` class method which does the function "aliasing".

The problem is that you INCLUDES modules does not re-export the modules correctly. This is important because this is the process that imports the functions into the caller namespaces. While this isn't hard to craft on your own, there is a handy module for this purpose [Import::Into](http://p3rl.org/Import::Into).

Here is an example contained within a single file, it should be easy enough to reinflate into multiple, the only important difference is in the Includes module. I have made some other superficial changes but those are more for my taste.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package PACKAGE1;

use parent 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw(Method1);

sub Method1 {
  print "PACKAGE1_Method1 \n";
}

package PACKAGE2;

use parent 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw(Method1);

sub Method1 {
  print "PACKAGE2_Method1 \n";
}

package Includes;

use Import::Into;

# uncomment in mulitple files
#use PACKAGE1 ();  # prevent import
#use PACKAGE2 ();  # ditto

sub import {
  my $class = shift;
  my $caller = caller;

  PACKAGE1->import::into( $caller );
  PACKAGE2->import::into( $caller );
}

package Test1;
Includes->import; # in seperate files replace with `use Includes;`

Method1();

package Test2;
Includes->import; # ditto

Method1();
```

A real world example is the module [`utf8::all`](https://metacpan.org/source/DOHERTY/utf8-all-0.009/lib/utf8/all.pm) which makes extensive use of this mechanism to load lots of unicode stuff into the caller package.

**Edit**

To allow importing specific things from the `Includes` module, you could have it inherit from `Exporter` as well and craft its `@EXPORT` and `@EXPORT_OK` to do what you mean. Otherwise, you could continue with `Import::Into` and make something like bundles.

```
sub import {
  my $class  = shift;
  my $bundle = shift;

  my $caller = caller;

  if ($bundle eq 'Bundle1') {
    PACKAGE1->import::into( $caller );
    ... # other things in Bundle1
  } elsif ($bundle eq 'Bundle2') {
    PACKAGE2->import::into( $caller );
    ... # other things in Bundle2
  }
}
```

Then in your test modules

```
use Includes 'Bundle1';
```

In short crafting your own `import` method is not that hard, and every little is magical about `Exporter`. Once you learn about symbol table manipulation your don't need it or `Import::Into`, though it is a slightly more advanced topic. Here is a question I asked about it much earlier in my Perl days: [Demystifying the Perl glob (*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865447/demystifying-the-perl-glob)

All that said, if object-oriented concepts of inheritance and polymorphism will do the job, you might want to investigate that route too. Here is an example of that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package PACKAGE1;

sub Method1 {
  my $class = shift;
  print "PACKAGE1_Method1 \n";
}

sub Method2 {
  my $class = shift;
  print "PACKAGE1_Method2 \n";
}

package PACKAGE2;

# if multiple files use this
#use parent 'PACKAGE1';
# rather than
our @ISA = 'PACKAGE1';

# any methods in PACKAGE2 will override those declared in PACKAGE1 

sub Method1 {
  my $class = shift;
  print "PACKAGE2_Method1 \n";
}

package Test1;

# in seperate files need to use
#use PACKAGE2;

PACKAGE2->Method1();
PACKAGE2->Method2();

package Test2;

# ditto
#use PACKAGE1
#use PACKAGE2

PACKAGE2->Method1();
PACKAGE2->Method2();

# you can still use PACKAGE1 and get the originals
PACKAGE1->Method1();
PACKAGE1->Method2();
```

See now there is no `Includes` package and no symbols are imported into the `Test*` namespaces. `PACKAGE2` provides `Method2` because it inherits from `PACKAGE1` and it does not override the method declaration with one of its own.

Comment: Hi Joel,Thanks. It works. Please check the edited question. I have given the scenario what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @InnovWelt, do you understand concepts of inheritance and polymorphism? If not read up about them. If so and this still won't get you where you want, then see my edit.

Comment: I do know some of the concepts of Inheritance, Including Function overriding, polymorphism. My intention is that, in Tests.pm file, the function call should be `Method1()`, It should not depend on any specific packages (like `PACKAGE2->Method1()`). Because, the situation is, **the tests will be same (including function calls). Only the Implementation of the particular function should differ based on the preference**