# Perl `use` - import is not called twice?

Tags: perl, package, perl-module

Doubt in perl basics `use`

it is somewhat similar to my other question [Perl: Two packages in same file...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658911/perl-two-packages-in-same-file-cannot-import-same-package)

consider a perl script:

**Script.pl**

```
use INCLUDES;
```

**INCLUDES.pm**

```
package INCLUDES;
use Exporter;

############# MY DOUBT STARTS HERE ###############
use Module1;
use Module2;
##################################################

our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw();

sub import {

  print 'INCLUDES imported to ' . caller . "\n";

}
```

**Module1.pm**

```
package Module1;

use strict;
use Exporter;
use INCLUDES;    #####=> INCLUDES.pm 'use'd

our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw();

1;
```

**Module2.pm**

```
package Module2;

use strict;
use Exporter;
use INCLUDES;  #####=> INCLUDES.pm 'use'd

our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = ();

1;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
D:\Do_analysis>Script.pl
INCLUDES imported to main
```

According to perl docs, `use INCLUDES;` in Module1 & Module2 =>  `BEGIN {require 'INCLUDES.pm'; 'INCLUDES'->import();}` . So, the `import()` should be called in Module1.pm , Module2.pm also.

I would expect the output as something like below,

**EXPECTED OUTPUT** ??

```
D:\Do_analysis>Script.pl
INCLUDES imported to main
INCLUDES imported to Module1
INCLUDES imported to Module2
```

But why is the execution not as expected?

**UPDATED**

This is what I am trying to achieve, by having the INCLUDES.pm file.

[image: Module library]

Note that: `PACKAGE2` might want to access PACKAGE3, PACKAGE4 etc. Instead of `use`ing all the modules inside `PACKAGE2` seperately, I would like to create a Library `INCLUDES` and `use` it in all other modules.

Is this approach valid? or recommendable?

I appreciate any idea about how to achieve this.
Thanks!

Comment: Just incidentally, this smells like bad design. Circular module dependencies are rarely needed in good code, and modules that exist just to load a bunch of other modules (especially exporting ones) are also questionable. It looks like you're building a "big pile of junk" pattern. :)

Comment: Yes. I can understand. but i am still not aware, if there is any other way to achieve the architecture in the given picture.

Answer (score 9):

If you were to move

```
use Module1;
use Module2;
```

below `sub import { ... }`, you'd get the expected behaviour.

---

The problem is that you execute `Module1.pm` before the compiler even reaches `sub import` in `INCLUDES.pm`.

When `Module1.pm` does `use INCLUDES;`, Perl says "oh, it's already loaded" (in response to `require`) and "oh, it doesn't have an `import`" (in response to `import`), since the part of `INCLUDES.pm` that would have created `import` hasn't been compiled yet. Same for `Module2.pm`.

Generally speaking, if you have a modules that include each other (directly or otherwise), you're doing something wrong (in terms of design), and you'll end up having to deal with such issues. You might find [Mini-Tutorial: Mutual Use of Exporting Modules](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=778639) useful in dealing with these issues.

Answer (score 3):

You have circular dependencies between your modules. `main` uses `INCLUDES`, `INCLUDES` uses `Module1`, and `Module1` uses `INCLUDES` (`Module2` is basically irrelevant here, except to act the same as `Module1`). If perl did the naïve thing, this would cause an infinite loop (or at least a stack overflow), as every time perl tried to compile `INCLUDES` it would lead to a compilation of `Module1`, and every time perl tried to compile `Module1` it would lead to a compilation of `INCLUDES`.

Since we don't want that to happen, perl has to do something different. What it does instead is to ignore any request to compile a module that's already compiled *or that it's already in the process of compiling*. So the flow of events is:

1. Perl begins compiling `script.pl` and enters the package `main`.
2. Perl sees `use INCLUDES;`, loads `INCLUDES.pm`, and begins compiling it.
3. At the line `package INCLUDES;`, perl enters the package `INCLUDES`.
4. Perl sees `use Module1;`, loads `Module1.pm`, and begins compiling it.
5. At the line `package Module1`, perl enters the package `Module1`.
6. Perl sees the `use INCLUDES;`, realizes that it's already in the process of compiling `INCLUDES.pm`, and doesn't attempt to compile it again.
7. As a result of `use INCLUDES;` perl tries to call `INCLUDES->import`, but the import method hasn't been defined yet (we suspended compilation of `INCLUDES` at step 4 to start compiling `Module1`).
8. Compilation of `Module1` completes and we go back to `INCLUDES`.
9. Perl calls `Module1->import` from `INCLUDES`.
10. Compilation of `INCLUDES` completes, including the `use Module2` and the definition of `sub import`. Perl goes back to `main`.
11. `INCLUDES->import` is called from `main` and your message is printed.
12. Compilation of `script.pl` completes.
13. `script.pl` has nothing to do at runtime, and perl exits.

Comment: Thanks for shedding some lights on compiling process. I have updated my question abt what i am trying to do. I do not understand where i should do `use / require`.