# What do Perl identifiers starting with an asterisk * represent?

Tags: regex, perl

I have this sub-routine which has identifiers defined like

```
*VALID_NAME_REG_EX = \"[ a-zA-Z0-9_#.:@=-]+";
*MACRO_VALID_NAME  = \"MACRO_VALID_NAME";
```

I looked into the file further. They are referenced as `$MACRO_VALID_NAME`.

I guess it's substituting the value with right side of string, but I am not sure of this and want a confirmation.

Comment: More information on constant variables and typeglobs can also be found in  Chapter 7 in [Mastering Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920012702.do) and chapter 1.21 in [Perl Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596003135.do)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Demystifying the Perl glob (\*)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865447/demystifying-the-perl-glob)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
*VALID_NAME_REG_EX = \"[ a-zA-Z0-9_#.:@=-]+";
```

The effect this has is to assign `$VALID_NAME_REG_EX` as an identifier for the Perl string literal `"[ a-zA-Z0-9_#.:@=-]+"`

This is different from saying

```
$VALID_NAME_REG_EX = "[ a-zA-Z0-9_#.:@=-]+"
```

which *copies* the string into the space assigned to `$VALID_NAME_REG_EX` so it may later be altered

Perl literals have to be read-only to make any sense, so the result of the assignment is to make `$VALID_NAME_REG_EX` a *read-only* variable, otherwise known as a constant. If you try assigning to it you will get a message something like

> Modification of a read-only value attempted

Comment: @mattfreake: It's not the typeglob that makes it read-only, it's that it's pointing at a Perl string literal, which is inherently unmodifiable. If I say `*var_b = \$var_a` then I have made `$var_b` refer to the same place as `$var_a`, which is read-write

Comment: hi @Borodin, could you share more on why $VALID_NAME_REG_EX is read-only in this case? I posted a new question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53190329/perl-where-to-find-deep-knowledge-on-a-read-only-variable-created-by-var-0

Answer (score 3):

`*` in perl denotes a [typeglob](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles)

> Perl uses an internal type called a typeglob to hold an entire symbol table entry. The type prefix of a typeglob is a * , because it represents all types. This used to be the preferred way to pass arrays and hashes by reference into a function, but now that we have real references, this is seldom needed.
>
> The main use of typeglobs in modern Perl is create symbol table aliases. This assignment:
>
> `*this = *that;`
>
> makes `$this` an alias for `$that`, `@this` an alias for `@that`, `%this` an alias for `%that`, `&this` an alias for `&that`, etc. Much safer is to use a reference.