# perl: where to find deep knowledge on a read-only variable created by *VAR = \0

Tags: perl

I've learned a perl statement like:

```
*VAR = \0;
```

create a read-only `$VAR` in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35083240/2492255, I'm trying to find more documents to understand why `$VAR` is read-only in this case, but with no luck, could someone help to explain or point me to some documents on this topic?

Comment: I've checked that doc, but still unclear about it, what's the difference between `*VAR = \0` and `*VAR = 0`? the later is writable.

Comment: A good thing to query about, but just in case let me say this: you don't want to use this just so, in normal code. There are pragmas and modules for setting things to be read-only (constants).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*VAR` is the symbol table entry for the following:

- `$VAR`
- `@VAR`
- `%VAR`
- `&VAR`

(It also has a slot for a file handle, a directory handle, a format and more.)

Because they store a bunch of variables of different types, the symbol table entries are called "typeglobs", or "globs" for short.

Assigning a reference to a to a glob sets the slot of the appropriate type to the referenced variable. This means that assigning a reference to a scalar to `*VAR` sets `*VAR{SCALAR}`, the value returned by `$VAR`. Since you are passing a reference to a constant, `$VAR` returns that constant.

---

`*VAR = *OTHER;`, on the other hand, makes the left-hand side name an alias for the right-hand side name.

- It makes `$VAR` equivalent to `$OTHER`.
- It makes `@VAR` equivalent to `@OTHER`.
- It makes `%VAR` equivalent to `%OTHER`.
- It makes `&VAR` equivalent to `&OTHER`.
- etc

`*VAR = 0;` is treated as `*VAR = *{"0"};` which means `*VAR = *0;`. This means, among other things, that `$VAR` will return the current script's name (as `$0` would).

---

Reference: [Typeglobs and Filehandles](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles)

Comment: Trivia: Globs are weird because they're a type of variable (`*foo`) and a type of value that a scalar can contain (`$x = *foo;`). Everything else is one or the other.