# subroutines returning references to an array or hash and the role of + operator

Tags: perl

I found this feature in Perl and I'm not sure what it is.. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Say I have a simple function like below:

```
sub get_arr {
    [1..9];
}
```

Now I can display this to the output with:

```
say "@{+get_arr}";
```

What is the + operator in this context?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4833991/15261315